# Centralized ASP.NET error handling: <customErrors> vs. Application_Error. Is it possible to use both?

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, global-asax

Currently, we are doing error handling via `Application_Error` in `global.asax.vb`:

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    OurLibrary.HandleError(Me)
End Sub
```

`HandleError` then logs the error into a database, displays an informative message to the user and returns the correct status code (404 or 500) depending on the type of exception that occurred:

```
Public Shared Sub HandleError(httpApp As HttpApplication)
    ''# do some logging
    ...

    ''# show some details about the error and information about how to contact us
    httpApp.Response.Write(...)

    httpApp.Response.StatusCode = 404 or 500
    httpApp.Server.ClearError()
End Sub
```

`Server.ClearError` is necessary, because otherwise the default ASP.NET error handling kicks in and the user is shown -- depending on the current state of `<customErrors>` -- either the "yellow screen of death" or an information message about how `<customErrors>` can be turned off.

The drawback of using `ClearError` is that I can no longer use `<customErrors>` to override the error handling behaviour -- something which brought quite a bit of trouble during the recent [ASP.NET vulnerability](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/18/important-asp-net-security-vulnerability.aspx), where the recommended workaround was done using `<customErrors>`.

I know that I could use *only* `customErrors` and show the information for the user in the page referenced by the `defaultRedirect` attribute, but that would require me to add this error page to every single web project (rather than having everything nicely centralized in one library function).

Is it possible to do *regular* error handling in Application_Error, but still allow it to be overridden by `<customErrors>`? Is that even best practice or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

PS: Many of our applications are hosted on our customer's servers (instead of our own), so "put all information in the application log and show nothing to the user" is not really an option.

---

**Solution**: Replace `httpApp.Server.ClearError()` with

```
If Not HttpContext.Current.IsCustomErrorEnabled Then httpApp.Server.ClearError()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally most of the time I see people opting for an approach similar to what you are doing.  There are a number of benefits to doing things your way.

1. Errors are no longer written to the Application Log in windows, this helps to ensure that clutter/overhead is minimized.
2. You have an easy to deploy method to add your logging, as you mentioned.

There are a number of workarounds that I have noticed people using in the past, but the most common is for users to make their custom handler be aware of the CustomErrors setting.  So, basically your code would look at the response code that it wants to sent, then take action based on the custom errors.  That gets the best of both worlds really.

Comment: Thanks for reassuring me that this is "the right way" to do things; I was a bit sceptic after not being able to apply the vulnerability workaround without removing ClearError. Making my handler customErrors-aware, as you suggested, was a lot easier than expected: After digging a bit through the class library, I found that making `ClearError` dependent on the value of `HttpContext.Current.IsCustomErrorEnabled` was completely sufficient.